# Keybindings on a per-perspective basis in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse-rcp, key-bindings, perspectives

I have an Eclipse RCP application which uses some bindings from `org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration` in addition to its own keybindigs, which are defined through the extension `org.eclipse.ui.binding`. I defined my own binding scheme and set the defaultAcceleratorConfiguration as `parentId`, then activated that scheme from `plugin_customization.ini` so that I can override some binding

Currently, nearly all of my commands are in the `org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window` context. However, I would like some binding to only take effect when a certain perspective is selected.

*How could I change the current context so that when a perspective is selected or loaded (upon application launch, for example) a certain context is activated, then revert to the window context when it is deselected?* I am looking for a solution that interferes other perspectives minimally, that is, it should be able to be used by several perspectives in the workbech.

I did some `IPerspectiveListener3` trickery that indeed works. I activate the context when my perspective is activated, and deactivate it upon perspective deactivation. However, I wonder whether a less hackish solution exists.

Comment: Perspectives in eclipse 3.x are mostly layout without state.  Your solution is probably the most reliable way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the `IPerspectiveListener3` approach, and didn't run into any regressions. Yet.